# Prove that $n(a^2 - a + 1)^n \ge a^{2n} + a^{2n(1 - \frac{1}{n - 1})} + \cdots + a^{\frac{2n}{n - 1}} + 1$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, examples-counterexamples

> Given $a \ge 1$ and $n \ge 2$, prove that $$\large n(a^2 - a + 1)^n \ge a^{2n} + a^{2n\left(1 - \frac{1}{n - 1}\right)} + \cdots + a^{\frac{2n}{n - 1}} + 1$$

I've tried using the Chebyshev inequality for multiple powers of $a$ but it didn't work. The solution may involve basic elements of calculus, at which I suck. So please help me understand your problem understandably (obviously) because I am still weak at calculus if your solution includes calculus.

Comment: The RHS can be 'simplified' to

$$\frac{a^{2n^2/(n-1)}-1}{a^{2n/(n-1)}-1}$$

via geometric series partial sums. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Toying with Riemann sums gets you

$$\frac1a<\frac{\text{RHS}}{a^{2n}}-\frac{(n-1)(a-1)}{a\log a} < 1$$

for $a>1$, and similarly for $a<1$. Not sure if it helps.

Comment: Note that for $a < 1$, the RHS is $\geq 1$, while the LHS is $< 1$ for large $n$

Answer (score 2):

For $n=4$ let $a=x^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$4(x^6-x^3+1)^4\geq x^{24}+x^{16}+x^8+1.$$
Are you sure that it's true?

Try $x=1.1.$

For $n=3$ your inequality is true:
$$3(a^2-a+1)^3-(a^6+a^3+1)=(a-1)^4(2a^2-a+2)\geq0.$$

Comment: For now, I have only added the condition $n \ge 1$. I'll come back to this later. At last, do you have any suggestions as to improving this problem?